# Efficient String trim

Tags: string, performance, rust

I have a `String` value and I want to [`trim()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/string/struct.String.html#method.trim) it. I can do something like:

```
let trimmed = s.trim().to_string();
```

But that will always create a new `String` instance, even though in real life the string is much more likely to be already trimmed. In order to avoid the redundant new `String` creation, I could do something like this:

```
let ss = s.trim();
let trimmed = if ss.len() == s.len() { s } else { ss.to_string() };
```

But that is quite verbose. Is there a more concise way to do the above?

Comment: I both like and hate the phrase "Premature optimization is the root of all evil", as it is generally true, but at the same time can be misleading and dangerous. Compeletely ignoring (not thinking) about performance in advance can often lead to bad design decisions. My question in particular doesn't pose such a risk, but I just don't like using such generalized statements. I *know* in most cases the redundant `String` creation won't be such a big performance problem, but sometimes it can make a difference, so that's why I care.

Comment: The most efficient thing would be to avoid creating a new String at all, and instead use a reference.

Comment: @PitaJ Yes, but that's not always possible. Sometimes `&str` is simply not enough, so I'm particularly asking about `String` to `String`.

Comment: I can't think of a more concise way to do it. As it is, it seems maximally concise: You need to tell the compiler to trim the string, and then if the strings are the same length return the original string, otherwise make a new string. There isn't a "trim but return the original string if they're equal" method on String (although, of course, you could write one using your own TrimOwned trait)

Comment: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9bfb221966ffc65343dd8bdaba883066)

Comment: Custom trait for consuming trim function: [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=3486bf0a09bb3ddfd32208eafb3dc395) @lkolbly

Comment: Reminds me of [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html), but I'm not sure how useful it is in this situation. Maybe have `trim` return `Cow<str>` and call `into_owned` on it?

Comment: @at54321 This seems to me like something that could be optimized later on. Why don't you simply `let trimmed = s.trim().to_string();`, put a comment `//TODO: optimize?` and then profile your program later on, to see if it's worth the effort? I 100% agree on you saying "Compeletely ignoring (not thinking) about performance in advance can often lead to bad design decisions", but what you're doing here is not a design decision, is it?

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of a more concise way to do it. As it is, it seems maximally concise: You need to tell the compiler to trim the string, and then if the strings are the same length return the original string, otherwise make a new string. There isn't a "trim but return the original string if they're equal" method on String.

That said, you could make your own trait `TrimOwned` which had such a method, for example (implementation courtesy of StackOverflower):

```rust
trait TrimOwned {
    fn trim_owned(self) -> Self;
}

impl TrimOwned for String {
    fn trim_owned(self) -> Self {
        let s = self.trim();
        
        if s.len() == self.len() {
            self
        } else {
            s.to_string()
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let left  = "    left".to_string();
    let right = "right   ".to_string();
    let both  = "  both  ".to_string();

    println!("'{}'->'{}'", left.clone(),  left.trim_owned());
    println!("'{}'->'{}'", right.clone(), right.trim_owned());
    println!("'{}'->'{}'", both.clone(),  both.trim_owned());
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=d8197358ca93c7c0f9e4b8cf64edb88b)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I cannot give you a more concise version. But I can tell you that there still is more room for premature optimization:

- When trimming on the right, you only need to shorten the string, there is obviously no need for reallocating
- You can't easily do the "shorten the string" trick when trimming to the left, since a string must always start at index 0 of its allocated area. But when you allocate a new string, you end up copying its contents, so you could as well just move the string content inside the already allocated area.

One nifty and reasonably fast way of implementing this is `String::drain`:

```rust
fn trim_owned(mut trim: String) -> String {
    trim.drain(trim.trim_end().len()..);
    trim.drain(..(trim.len() - trim.trim_start().len()));
    trim
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you, I was looking for that (looked in the wrong place, on Vec). I also should have used `String::as_mut_vec`. But now that I've [played](https://github.com/jcaesar/trim_owned_rs/blob/5fe4d651d6c30268a12772d6dbe7bbe987999d2f/src/impl.rs#L32) around a bit, I think drain is fast and concise.